# Displaying only selected records on map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, australia

How to make selected records display on the map only?

So far, I've selected by attributes and created the clause for the records I needed. These records are highlighted on the map but also the other selections that are not selected.

I want for only these selected records to show up on the map. And how can I specify this selection, so only for those showing up in Australia?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

After you have made your selection you can create a selection layer from those selected features.  Then turn off the layer you made the selection from to only see the selected feature.

See [Selection layers](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/selection-layers.htm) for more information from Esri.